# Nesting HTML tables inside javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, nested-table

I am trying to create a table in js that will contain text in the first column and a repeated HTML table (id 'questable') with a for loop.  I do not know how to isolate the repeated HTML table from the rest of the document HTML.  When using the += operator within the second createTextNode(), I get the desired 'questable' output but also all of the building HTML content as the loop continues.  Help! I am very new to all of this...  thanks.

```
<table id="questable" name="qtable" class="questiontable"><tr><td style="text-align:center; width: 5%;"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font><input name="Most"  type="radio"  onclick="TestCheckMarkQ(0, 0)"  value="3"></td><td style="width:95%;">HIGH</td></tr><tr><td style="text-align:center; width: 5%;"><input type="radio" name="Most" value="2"  onclick="TestCheckMarkQ(1, 0)"  /></td><td style="width:95%;">MEDIUM</td></tr><tr><td style="text-align:center; width: 5%;"><input type="radio" name="Most" value="4"  onclick="TestCheckMarkQ(2, 0)"></td><td style="width:95%;">LOW</td></tr></table>

<table id="filrank"></table>

<script>
function fun3() 
{

var e=document.getElementById('filters').rows.length;
//alert(e);

var i;

for (i=0; i<e; i++)
{
    var x = document.getElementById("filrank");
    document.body.appendChild(x);

    var y = document.createElement("TR");
    y.setAttribute("id", "tr"+i);
    document.getElementById("filrank").appendChild(y);

    var z = document.createElement("TD");
    var d = document.getElementsByName('fil')[i].value
    var t = document.createTextNode(d);
    z.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById("tr"+i).appendChild(z);

    var zz = document.createElement("TD");
    var dd=document.getElementById('questable').innerHTML;
    tt=document.createTextNode(document.getElementById('filrank').innerHTML+=dd)
    zz.appendChild(tt);
    document.getElementById("tr"+i).appendChild(zz);
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is that you have to put a for inside the table tag

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer using insertAdjacentHTML in the last grouping of the script.  This gives me the output that I wanted.  The HTML table now repeats for each iteration of the loop in the second column of the table.

```
<table id="questable" name="qtable" class="questiontable"><tr><td style="text-align:center; width: 5%; border: 1px solid black;"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font><input name="Most"  type="radio"  onclick="TestCheckMarkQ(0, 0)"  value="3"></td><td style="width:5%;">HIGH</td><td style="text-align:center; width: 5%;"><input type="radio" name="Most" value="2"  onclick="TestCheckMarkQ(1, 0)"  /></td><td style="width:5%;">MEDIUM</td><td style="text-align:center; width: 5%;"><input type="radio" name="Most" value="4"  onclick="TestCheckMarkQ(2, 0)"></td><td style="width:5%;">LOW</td></tr></table>


<table id="filrank"></table>

<section>

<script>
function fun3() 
{

var e=document.getElementById('filters').rows.length;
//alert(e);

var i;

for (i=0; i<e; i++)
{
    var x = document.getElementById("filrank");
    document.body.appendChild(x);

    var y = document.createElement("TR");
    y.setAttribute("id", "tr"+i);
    document.getElementById("filrank").appendChild(y);

    var z = document.createElement("TD");
    var d = document.getElementsByName('fil')[i].value
    var t = document.createTextNode(d);
    z.appendChild(t);
    y.appendChild(z);

    var z = document.createElement("TD");
    var d=document.getElementById('questable').innerHTML;
    z.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',d);
    y.appendChild(z);
}
}
</script>
```